# Run code when YouTube loads in more video's

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

```
$(".yt-simple-endpoint.inline-block.style-scope.ytd-thumbnail")
```

This is the path to YouTube thumbnail video url's, it is a array that starts with 20-32 url's. The array increase in length when you load in more video's and the array changes when you click on a new video.

I want to run code every time the array increase in length and when the array changes. Atm i'm running a SetInterval that works fine, but I want it to run in a proper way.

Some example code:

```
var obj = $(".yt-simple-endpoint.inline-block.style-scope.ytd-thumbnail")
for (j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) { 
$([obj[j]]).append("<h2 class=overlaytext>Hello !</h2>")
}
```

However YouTube is dynamic, my example code there only runs on all the video's that is loaded after a refresh, but not when YouTube dynamically changes.

Any suggestions(prefer jquery suggestions)?

Comment: Comment if you want me to provide more info, I have tried to include as much as I can. I can include my whole code, but its long, if any1 wants that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var continuation = $("yt-next-continuation")
continuation.on("yt-load-next-continuation", event=>{
})
```